# BIND and OpenVPN on the same port (different IP and interfaces)

Tags: networking, openvpn, bind

I have 2 network interfaces: **eth0** has IPv4 `104.x.y.44` and **eth1** has `104.x.y.38`.
BIND is listening on `104.x.y.44:53` and I want OpenVPN to be on 104.x.y.38:53 (udp mode).
However OpenVPN fails to start:

`Sat Jun 13 20:12:02 2015 us=287547 TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET]104.x.y.38:53: Address already in use`

But why? Bind is listening only on 104.x.y.44:53.

Can you also explain me why do these servers use TCP ports if they both work with UDP?

Comment: look at the output of `netstat -unlp | grep :53`

Answer (score 0):

Removing `query-source address * port 53;` from BIND config solved the problem.